# How many different ways are there to choose 5 items from 12 distinct items if…

Tags: combinatorics

How many different ways are there to choose 5 items from 12 distinct items if…

a. (5 pt.) the order of the items matters and repetition of items is not allowed?

b. (5 pt.) the order of the items matters and repetition of items is allowed?

c. (5 pt.) the order of the items does not matter and repetition of items is not allowed?

d. (5 pt.) the order of the items does not matter and repetition of items is allowed?

**My Work**

a) $P(12,5)$

b)$12^5$

c)$\binom{12}{5}$

d)Please explain this

Can you please verify my work

Comment: I don't understand your reasoning for $b$.  Hint:  there are $12$ possibilities for the first choice, $12$ possibilities for the second choice, ...

Comment: So, the b is $12^5$ right

Comment: Yes, that is right.  For $d$, I think [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is the way to go.

Comment: Then, what about C

Comment: Your answers for $a,c$ are correct,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) Correct

b) No. You have 12 choices on the first item. 12 on the second. 12 on the third, fourth and fifth. So it should be $12^5$.

c) Correct

d) This is a bit tricky, I shall explain this below.

---

We have $C$ for combination, $P$ for permutation, and the first time I was taught this one (order does not matter + repetition allowed), my teacher called it $H$ although I am not sure if it is standard notation.

Anyway, the formula in general is $H_r^{n}=C_r^{n+r-1}$.

The reasoning behind this is as follows (for simplicity we shall take $H_5^{12}$ as in this case as an example):

Let the $12$ possible choices be $a,b,c,\dots,l$.

We don't care about the order here, we only care about how many of each item you choose, and with each choice, we can assign with it a unique "binary code".

For example, if you choose $aabbc$, then we write $0010010111111111$ where the first two $0$'s represent the two $a$'s, after the $1$ we have two $0$'s for the two $b$'s, and so on.

As another example, $abjkl$ is represented by $0101111111101010$.

In this way, each possible choice can be represented by a string of five $0$'s and eleven $1$'s for a total of $16$ numbers. So to count all possible choices, we simply have to choose the five places to insert the $0$'s.

This is given by $C_5^{16}$, hence $H_5^{12}=C_5^{16}$

Comment: Isn't $C(16,4)$

Comment: Why should it be $C_4^{16}$?

Comment: @tienlee  If the number of items of type $k$ is $x_k$, then we want the number of solutions of the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \cdots + x_{12} = 5$$ in the nonnegative integers.  The number of such solutions is $$\binom{12 + 5 - 1}{12 - 1} = \binom{12 + 5 - 1}{5}$$ where the expression $\binom{12 + 5 - 1}{12 - 1}$ counts the number of ways of choosing which $12 - 1 = 11$ positions of $12 + 5 - 1$ positions required for five ones and eleven addition signs will be filled with addition signs and the expression $\binom{12 + 5 - 1}{5}$ comes from choosing the positions of the ones in the same row.

Answer (score 2):

I will leave you with a quick guide on how to tackle these problems.

Suppose you have $n$ distinct objects, and you want to select $r$ out of these $n$ objects. Then, if:

- Order *is* relevant and repetition is *not* allowed: look at the possible *permutations* of size $r$ which is given by 
  $$P(n,r)=\frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$$
  with $0\leq r \leq n.$
- Order *is* relevant and repetition *is* allowed: look at the possible *arrangements* of size $r$, which is given by $n^r$, with $n,r \geq 0.$
- Order is *not* relevant and repetitions are *not* allowed: look at the possible *combinations* of size $r,$ which is given by
  $$C(n,r)= \binom{n}{r}=\frac{n!}{(n-r)! r!}$$
  with $0 \leq r \leq n.$
- Order is *not* relevant and repetition *is* allowed: look at the possible combinations with repetitions, which is given by
  $$\binom{n+r-1}{r}\ \ $$
  with $n,r \geq 0.$